# Unit testing with JMS (ActiveMQ)

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jms, activemq-classic, jmstemplate

How to do unit testing with JMS ? Is it some de-facto for this ?

I googled something
- Unit testing for JMS: http://activemq.apache.org/how-to-unit-test-jms-code.html
- jmsTemplate: activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas.html
- mockRunner : mockrunner.sourceforge.net/

Do you have any good experience on those and suggestion for me ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my experience (after trying to do the same thing) when you are using JMS you are doing something like

1) Get JMS Message
2) Extract Object from Message
3) Do something with Object

From that point of view I would suggest you unit test #3 but don't bother unit testing #1 or #2 -- don't test the framework -- focus on testing your code.  I think it's of little benefit to (unit) test your infrastructure (similarly EJB infrastructure etc.).  Things like that are better left to integration / system testing.

Answer (score 5):

For simple integration tests you can run the [ActiveMQ broker in embedded mode](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html). With Maven, this can be automated so you do not even have to download and install the ActiveMQ message broker.

Answer (score 1):

i looking for same kind of thing
I've done it once with JMock, with it ypu can test the message creattion and combined with hamcrest you can achieve nice things.

Comment: and what if you
1) get a message
2)do some tricks 
3)send a message to a specific destination??