# Do I have to use jetty embeded server to test my active mq structure in a Spring project?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, activemq-classic

Do I have to use jetty embeded server to test my active mq structure in a Spring project? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, add context your listener container bean like the following:

```
<bean id="sampleListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="concurrency" value="20-100"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="sampleDestination"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="sampleListenerConsumer"/>
</bean>
```

Secondly,

```
DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = BeanProvider.getBeanFactory().getBean("sampleListenerContainer", DefaultMessageListenerContainer.class);
container.start();
```

Similarly,

```
container.stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following links from ActiveMQ:

- [How to unit test JMS code](http://activemq.apache.org/how-to-unit-test-jms-code.html)
- [Integration Tests > Example Testing Scenario](http://activemq.apache.org/example-testing-scenario.html)
- [Unit testing with JMS (ActiveMQ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870431/unit-testing-with-jms-activemq)

Comment: Many thanks, I am gonna give a look at them. Then I will share the result. Cheers.